# Magento 2 : override configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, overrides, xml, magento-2.1.3

Can u tell me **which XML file bind all files to create configurable product** so, I can override that file in my custom module at front-end side. Exactly, I want to **create configurable button** and by doing click on that button open side modal perform all steps to create configurable product in my custom module.

**Give list of all `xml` and `phtml` files used in configurable product**